# Buefy, b-datepicker разваливается после после обновления страницы

Tags: vue.js, datepicker

Есть блок с несколькими датапикерами:

```
<div 
  v-for="upcoming_race, index in profile.upcoming_races" 
  :key="index" 
  class="profile__upcoming-races-list margin_regular"
>
  <div :class="['columns', 'is-vcentered', isGapless ? 'is-gapless' : '']">
    <div class="column is-4 is-offset-4 profile__datepicker">
      <b-datepicker 
        position="is-bottom-right" 
        placeholder="Select date"
        v-model="upcoming_race.date" 
        :min-date="maxDobDate" 
        :years-range="[-100,100]"
      />
    </div>
  <div class="column desktop">
</div>
```

После сохранения данных и обновления страницы в консоль валятся ошибки такого вида:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected Date, Array, got String with value "2022-04-22T17:00:00.000Z".

В доку смотрел, пробовал использовать пропсы, но не пойму как правильно их применить. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: Судя по ошибке, ожидается, что какой-то параметр будет иметь тип Date или Array, а вместо этого приходит String. Я бы проверил ```:min-date="maxDobDate" ```.

Comment: @ВикторКарев из `maxDobDate` возвращается `new Date()`. Это же вычисляемое свойство используется в других рабочих, но одиночных датапикерах.